# Android Room @Relation and Indexes

Tags: android, android-room

I have this class in my Room setup, which combines data from my `states` table with the corresponding data from my `countries` table:

```
public class StateWithCountryData {

    @Embedded
    public State state;

    @Relation(parentColumn = "country_id", entityColumn = "_id", entity = Country.class)
    public Country country;
}
```

As you can see in my **@Relation** code, my `states`.`country_id` column is joined to my `countries`.`_id` column.

What I would like to know is whether the @Relation code will create an automatic index on `states`.`country_id` or do I need to create the index myself in my **State** entity class?

If the latter, how do I add the required [index](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room) to my **State** entity class? Here it is:

```
@Entity(tableName = "states")
public class State {

    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "_id")
    private long stateId;

    @NonNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "state_name")
    private String stateName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "country_id")
    private long countryId;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_modified")
    private Date lastModified;

    public State(long stateId, @NonNull String stateName, long countryId, Date lastModified) {
        this.stateId = stateId;
        this.stateName = stateName;
        this.countryId = countryId;
        this.lastModified = lastModified;
    }

    public long getStateId() {
        return stateId;
    }

    public void setStateId(long stateId) {
        this.stateId = stateId;
    }

    @NonNull
    public String getStateName() {
        return stateName;
    }

    public void setStateName(@NonNull String stateName) {
        this.stateName = stateName;
    }

    public long getCountryId() {
        return countryId;
    }

    public void setCountryId(long countryId) {
        this.countryId = countryId;
    }

    public Date getLastModified() {
        return lastModified;
    }

    public void setLastModified(Date lastModified) {
        this.lastModified = lastModified;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I would like to know is whether the @Relation code will create an automatic index on states.country_id or do I need to create the index myself in my State entity class?

The way to check is to look at the generated code for the @database e.g. you would get something like :-

```
final SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback _openCallback = new RoomOpenHelper(configuration, new RoomOpenHelper.Delegate(1) {
  @Override
  public void createAllTables(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
    _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Country` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `name` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))");
    _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `states` (`_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `state_name` TEXT NOT NULL, `country_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `last_modified` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`_id`))");
    _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)");
    _db.execSQL("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO room_master_table (id,identity_hash) VALUES(42, '008d8fa1f719c970d7a1182e9e43f80b')");
  }
.....
```

As you can see the answer is **no**.

> If the latter, how do I add the required index to my State entity class?

You can use :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "states"
    , indices = {@Index(name = "ixCountryId", value = "country_id")} //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
    )
```

And now the generated code is :-

```
@Override
  protected SupportSQLiteOpenHelper createOpenHelper(DatabaseConfiguration configuration) {
    final SupportSQLiteOpenHelper.Callback _openCallback = new RoomOpenHelper(configuration, new RoomOpenHelper.Delegate(1) {
      @Override
      public void createAllTables(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) {
        _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Country` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `name` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`id`))");
        _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `states` (`_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `state_name` TEXT NOT NULL, `country_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `last_modified` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`_id`))");
        _db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `ixCountryId` ON `states` (`country_id`)");
        _db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS room_master_table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,identity_hash TEXT)");
        _db.execSQL("INSERT OR REPLACE INTO room_master_table (id,identity_hash) VALUES(42, '74ee12325d1720c24abff0e5ce479d81')");
```

i.e. the line

```
 _db.execSQL("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `ixCountryId` ON `states` (`country_id`)");
```

has been added.

**A simpler option** is to code at the @ColumnInfo level instead of coding indicies at the @Entity level e.g.

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "country_id", index = true)
private long countryId;
```

This will auto-generate the index name and result, in the above case, in the following being included in the generated code (instead of the previously shown line):-

```
_db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `index_states_country_id` ON `states` (`country_id`)");
```

You could also use both (not something that you would do as it's a waste/inefficient) which would result in :-

```
    _db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `ix01` ON `states` (`country_id`)");
    _db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `index_states_country_id` ON `states` (`country_id`)");
```

- coding at the @Entity level offers greater options such as complex (multi-column) or unique indexes.

> or do I need to create the index myself in my State entity class?

Not necessarily and perhaps probably not as the index appears to have a negative impact, although depending upon the number of countries and states, if quite low, then perhaps a negligible impact.

Consider the following test code which creates 10000 countries and 500000 states randomly allocated to countries (approx 50 states per country).

Using two core queries :-

```
SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id > 500;
SELECT * FROM states JOIN Country ON Country.id = states.country_id WHERE country_id < 500;
```

before and after the creation of the index the timings prior to indexing are

```
SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id > 500
> OK
> Time: 0.563s


SELECT * FROM states JOIN Country ON Country.id = states.country_id WHERE country_id < 500
> OK
> Time: 0.074s
```

and after the creation of the index are :-

```
SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id > 500
> OK
> Time: 2.764s


SELECT * FROM states JOIN Country ON Country.id = states.country_id WHERE country_id < 500
> OK
> Time: 0.158s
```

So slower with the index (about 5 times slower for the first query and 9.5 slower for the second query).

---

The code also does an EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN before the queries are run.

Before Index creation :-

Query 1 :-

[image]

Query 2 :-

[image]

After Index creation

Query 1 :-

[image]

Query 2 :-

[image]

**The Code used (using Navicat)** :-

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Country;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS states;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Country` (`id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `name` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`id`));
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `states` (`_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `state_name` TEXT NOT NULL, `country_id` INTEGER NOT NULL, `last_modified` TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(`_id`));

/* Load data into the Country table */
WITH RECURSIVE cte1(counter,base) AS (
    SELECT 1, 'COUNTRY_A'
    UNION ALL SELECT counter+1,'COUNTRY_A' FROM cte1 LIMIT 10000
)
INSERT INTO Country (name) SELECT base||counter FROM cte1; 

/* Load fata into the states table */
WITH RECURSIVE cte1(counter,base,cid) AS (
  SELECT 1,'STATE_S', (abs(random()) % (SELECT count() FROM Country)) + 1
    UNION ALL SELECT 
        counter+1,
        'STATE_S',
      (abs(random()) % (SELECT count() FROM Country)) + 1   
    FROM cte1 LIMIT 500000
)
INSERT INTO states (state_name, country_id) SELECT base||counter, cid FROM cte1; 

EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT * FROM states JOIN Country ON Country.id = states.country_id WHERE country_id < 500;
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id > 500;

SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id > 500;
SELECT * FROM states JOIN Country ON Country.id = states.country_id WHERE country_id < 500;

/* Create the Index */
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `ix01` ON `states` (`country_id`);

EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT * FROM states JOIN Country ON Country.id = states.country_id WHERE country_id < 500;
EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN
SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id > 500;

SELECT * FROM states WHERE country_id > 500;
SELECT * FROM states JOIN Country ON Country.id = states.country_id WHERE country_id < 500;

/* Show states per country */
SELECT Country.name,count() AS states_inCountry FROM States JOIN Country ON country_id = Country.id GROUP BY country_id;

/* Clean up */
DROP INDEX IF EXISTS ix01;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS states;
DROP TABLE If EXISTS Country;
```

- Note this may be a little bit of an unfair comparison/test as the index creation may have an impact upon the subsequent run conditions. Ideally the queries should be run separately from each other and separate from the index creation.

Comment: Many thanks for your great answer. I thought it was just best practice to add indexes for lookup columns. When there aren't many rows, I can see why there wouldn't be much of a performance improvement, but wouldn't the additional storage required to hold the index data also be negligible?